# gtk keyval for keypad/numpad keys?

Tags: events, gtk, keyboard-events

This might be a silly question, but I'm trying to handle keyboard event in a gtk program. And I can't find in the documentation ( https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/plain/gdk/gdkkeysyms.h )the keyval for keypad/numpad keys such as '+' or '-'.

The GDK_KEY_plus and GDK_KEY_minus are reffering to the '+' and '-' at the top of the keyboard, not those on the numpad.

Thanks for reading.

ps : I'm using an azerty keyboard.

Comment: You want the `GDK_KEY_KP_*` constants.

Comment: Indeed, thanks a lot.
I was looking for KEY_PLUS or something like that, could have been searching a long time. (I can't validate comments as the answer to the question, you might want to respond using the "answer question" button if you want your badge points)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numpad constants are the `GDK_KEY_KP_*` (which stands for *keypad*) constants. `GDK_KEY_plus` is `GDK_KEY_KP_Add` and `GDK_KEY_minus` is `GDK_KEY_KP_Subtract`.